# dictionary being replaced and I am not sure why it is happening?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory

I have some code which is something along the lines of

```
storage = {}
for index, n in enumerate(dates):
    if n in specific_dates:
        for i in a_list:
            my_dict[i] = {}
            my_dict[i]["somthing"] = value
            my_dict[i]["somthing2"] = value_2
    else:
        #print(storage[dates[index - 1]["my_dict"][i]["somthing"])
         for i in a_list:
            my_dict[i] = {}
            my_dict[i][somthing] = different_value - storage[dates[index - 1]["my_dict"][i]["somthing"]
            my_dict[i]["somthing2"] = different_value_2
    storage[n]["my_dict"] = my_dict
```

The first pass will initiate the code in `if n in specific_dates:` the second pass goes to `for i in a_list:`

Essentially the code is getting a value set on specific dates and this value is then used for nonspecific dates that occur after the specific date until the next specific date overrides that value. However, at every date, i save a dictionary of values within a master dictionary called storage.

I found the problem which is when I print my_dict on the second pass `my_dict[i]` is literally an empty dictionary whereas prior to that loop it was filled. Where I have put the commented-out print line it would print `value`. I have fixed this by changing `storage[n]["my_dict"] = my_dict` to `storage[n]["my_dict"] = my_dict.copy()` and can now access `value`.

However, I do not really understand why this didnt work how I expected in the first place as I thought by assigning my_dict to storage it was creating new memory.

I was hoping someone could explain why this is happening and why `storage[dates[index - 1]["my_dict"][i]["somthing"]` doesn't create a new space in memory if that is indeed what is happening.

Comment: problem makes `my_dict[i] = {}` - it removes previous content.

Comment: In this code, whenever `my_dict[i]` is assigned, it also assigns `my_dict[i][somthing]` and `my_dict[i][something2]`.  So if you're seeing `my_dict[i]` as an empty dictionary, it must be coming from other code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Yes John Gordon that is correct but I thought as I was saving it to a seperate dictionary it would create a clone more or less which would be unaffected by changes to my_dict if that makes sense? Essentially I thought it would create a new pointer to another area of memory